# Garbage collection of static members

Tags: .net, garbage-collection

Will static members be ever collected by the garbage collector?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Objects referenced by static variables will only be garbage collected when the relevant `AppDomain` is garbage collected. In client applications, there's often just a single `AppDomain` which lives for the duration of the process. (An exception is when the application uses a plug-in architecture - different plug-ins may be loaded in different `AppDomain`s and the `AppDomain` may be unloaded later.)

In ASP.NET, "`AppDomain` recycling" happens periodically (for various reasons) - when this occurs, and the static variables within that `AppDomain` will no longer act as GC roots, and thus won't prevent objects being garbage collected.

If you were worried about an object being garbage collected while you still had a reference to it via a static variable, though, you can relax. While you can access the object, it won't be garbage collected.

Comment: Doesn't this create a great inefficiency?  I often create private static helper methods.  Or, all extension methods.  I wonder how much memory these consume?  If I have a helper method for an object, is it better to simply leave the helper as an instance so that it will be collected?

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey: If you have static methods, what memory are you imagining being consumed? If you have static *variables*, you've got global state, which is often a bad idea to start with. But methods themselves are a different matter.

Comment: My mistake.  I assumed methods get created on the stack/heap like variables do.  Apparently that is not the case.

Answer (score 6):

Members are not collected... Objects are.
So if you set the Ref. Type static member to null, any object it was previously pointing to would be collected. If not, it will hang around till the AppDomain goes down (Each AppDomain has its own set of static stuff)

Answer (score 3):

The short answer... No; all current implementations of the .NET garbage collector will not collect objects strongly referenced by static class member fields, until the Application Domain those static class member field strong references are associated with, is torn down.

The longer answer... Potentially yes; the garbage collector bases its decision to collect an object on reachability of the object, not on references (strong or weak) to the object. In theory, if the garbage collector could determine that no code would ever require a certain object again from a certain point onwards (that is, the object is not reachable from any code path), the GC would be allowed to collect that object, even if it were still strongly referenced by static class member fields. This is perfectly allowable, since you'd never notice, since no code would ever try access the static class member field that holds the reference to the object. You might ask, so why do I care if I am never going to access the object again via any of the strong references I hold to it? The reason you'd care is side-effects. For instance, you might assume by assigning a static class member field a reference to a SafeHandle object, representing a unmanaged resource, that the SafeHandle object would never be closed and would thus keep the unmanaged "object" it represents alive. This is only true for the current implementations of the GC. A future implementation of the GC could collect objects strongly referenced by static class member fields if those objects were no longer reachable by any of the remaining program code.

Answer (score 0):

A static member to a reference type is a reference, which may or may not point to an instance. If it points to an instance, said instance will not be collected until the static member is unloaded. If the type is loaded in a specific AppDomain, that can be unloaded. Otherwise it only happens when the application is terminated.